# Spring Annotations -java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required in spring+hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I am getting the error as in the question. My Dao Implement Class is as follows :

```
package com.argus.intenew;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao {

@Autowired
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;
    public UserDaoImpl() {
    }

    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean getCurrentSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void  setCurrentSessionFactory(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionfactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(UserMap userMap) {
        System.out.println("33333333333333333333");
        getHibernateTemplate().save(userMap);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUser() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from User");
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(UserMap user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserMap user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(user);
    }
}
```

And my configuration class is as follows:

```
package com.argus.intenew;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.argus.intenew"})
public class Webconfig  {
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("----------InDATAsource------------");
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyUser");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("XXX");
        System.out.println("----------OutofDATAsource------------");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        System.out.println("----------InsessionFactory------------");
        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        String[] pckage={"com.argus.intenew"};
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(pckage);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        System.out.println("----------Outof session------------");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        System.out.println("----------InhipProp------------");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ");
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, "true");
        System.out.println("----------outofhip------------");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public UserBoImpl userBo() {
       System.out.println("----------InUserBo------------");
       UserBoImpl userBo= new UserBoImpl();
       userBo.setUserDao(userDao());
       System.out.println("----------OutofUserbo------------");
       return userBo;
   }

   @Bean
   public UserDaoImpl userDao() {
       System.out.println("----------InUserDao------------");
       UserDaoImpl userDao=new UserDaoImpl();
       userDao.setCurrentSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
       System.out.println("----------OutofUserDao------------");
       return userDao;
   }
}
```

Anyone please help and tell me what is the correct way to do this with annotations.
Here I am not using any xml file.

Comment: If you're going to extend `HibernateDaoSupport`, you need to give the superclass a reference to your injected `SessionFactory` before you can use `getHibernateTemplate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DAO implementation is not leveraging its superclass correctly.

1. You're injecting a Spring `FactoryBean<SessionFactory>` when it really needs a Hibernate `SessionFactory`.
2. It's not actually using the injected dependency.
3. You're attempting to use `HibernateDaoSupport#getHibernateTemplate()` without giving it a reference to a `SessionFactory` or a `HibernateTemplate`.

Note that `HibernateDaoSupport` will create its own `HibernateTemplate` as long as you give it a `SessionFactory`.

I suggest you make the following changes:

1. **Remove** `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory` from `UserDaoImpl`
2. **Fix** configuration of `UserDaoImpl` by leveraging its inherited `setSessionFactory(SessionFactory)` method

So you actually end up with this DAO code:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao {
    @Override
    public void addUser(UserMap userMap) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(userMap);
    }
    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUser() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from User");
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(UserMap user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(user);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserMap user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(user);
    }
}
```

And this configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.argus.intenew"})  
public class Webconfig  {
    //snip...
    @Bean
    public UserDaoImpl userDao() {
        UserDaoImpl userDao=new UserDaoImpl();
        userDao.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return userDao;
    }
}
```

Note that it's ok to return the `FactoryBean` from the `sessionFactory()` configuration method since Spring will detect and utilize its lifecycle methods (via `InitializingBean` and `DisposableBean`), but you need to accommodate by calling the `FactoryBean` method `getObject()` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Don't user HibernateDaoSupport and/or HibernateTemplate. With the release of Hibernate 3.0.1 that support should be regarded deprecated. As mentioned in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight) implement the dao/repository based on plain hibernate.

Your dao will look like

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addUser(UserMap userMap) {
        System.out.println("33333333333333333333");
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(userMap);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUser() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(UserMap user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserMap user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
    }
}
```

As you are already using the `@ComponentScan` annotation (and I assume yo have your BO annotated with `@Service` and properly annotated with `@Autowired` there is no need to explictly configure you dao and service in the configuration.

```
@Configuration  
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.argus.intenew"})  
public class Webconfig  {  

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";  

    @Bean  
    public DataSource dataSource() {  
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();  
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyUser");  
        dataSource.setUsername("root");  
        dataSource.setPassword("XXX");  
        return dataSource;  
    }  

    @Bean  
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() { 
        AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();  
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        String[] pckage={"com.argus.intenew"};
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(pckage);  
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactory; 
    }  

    private Properties hibProperties() { 
        Properties properties = new Properties();  
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect ");  
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, "true"); 
        return properties;    
    } 

    @Bean  
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {  
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());  
    }  
}
```

A note regarding `DriverManagerDataSource` this is nice for testing but please don't use this in production (unless you want an application that doesn't perform). Use a proper JDBC Connection Pool instead.

A final note, if you really want productivity drop hibernate, switch to JPA and use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) for your repositories. Saves you writing a lot of implementation code. (And the best maintainable and testable code is code not written :) ).